# How to access a server

Tags: apache, download, private-key

I want to download my public key from a server. I received an ip adress, username and password. When I paste the ip adress into the search bar, I get directed to the apache test site.

This sites states "This page is used to test the proper operation of the Apache HTTP server after it has been installed. If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at this site is working properly."

How can I download my private key?
(If you could formulate your answer very easy, I would be very gratefull. I know nothing. Thank you!)

I cannot download my private key. Although, I have the ip adress, username and password.

Answer (score 1):

What is the username and password for? You are definitely not meant to access that IP from the browser.

Usually publicly hosted servers have a FTP server that can be accessed from a FTP client. I recommend you to download this one [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). Once you open the program, connect to the FTP server. In the session connect menu select FTP and add your IP address, username and the password. Don't change the port.

Comment: Hey Toka47,

Thank you for your answer.
I received these information from a company which did develop my website. They told me I can enter this server to download the private key. I have downloaded the WinSCP and I did enter the information. However, I get the error message No supported authentication methods available. What should I do next= )Do you have any turtorials which I can watch / read?)